# Refusal Of Visit Visa Germany

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas

As one of my friend got refusal for visit visa and they give him reason that "Your intention to leave the territory of the member states before expiry of the visa could not be ascertained.
My question is if he wants to appeal , he has to take appointment again for german embassy to submit letter in person and in the letter that he received they mentioned information regarding appeals that " an action with the Administrative Court in Berlin" , what does that mean ?

**Which is the best way to get a visa as soon as possible - by appeal or applying again?**

Comment: Unless your friend's material circumstances have changed in such a significant manner that the officer will be convinced that he is no longer a risk of overstaying, submitting another application will end with the same denial as the first.

Comment: please don't use ALL CAPS IT'S CONSIDERED SHOUTING

Answer (score 5):

When a German official makes a decision and you do not like the outcome, you can go to court. German courts are organized into criminal, civil, administrative and some other branches.

An appeal makes sense if the official made an obvious, simple error or if you have lots of money to spend on lawyers. It **probably** makes no sense in your case, but they need to tell you anyway. Being told that and where one can appeal is completely routine on German official documents, and does not suggest that one should appeal in the specific case.

How to convince a German visa official that you will leave again:

- Your friend needs a stable, well-documented job with an income exceeding the reasonable cost-of-living expenses. This is the key factor, and probably more important than the *balance* of the account.
- It might help if there are strong family ties to the homeland, real estate, etc.
- A well-thought-out itinerary with enough savings in the account to pay for the trip also helps.